# Ember- Binding Controller Value To Application Controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

For a proof of concept I tried to bound one value of a controller x to the application controller.

To be more specific, I bound the title property to the corresponding title property on the application controller.

However, it doesn't work and I can't figure out why.

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.SiteController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: "application",
    titleBinding: "controllers.application.title"
});

App.IndexController = App.SiteController.extend({
    init: function() {
        this._super();
        this.set("title", "Home");
    }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1743/edit

Have I understood bindings wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bindings aren't updated when inside of the `init` method, because this your template don't change. You need to register some function with `on('init')`, so it will be called after the object is initialized.

You can replace your IndexController with the following:

```
App.IndexController = App.SiteController.extend({
    setupTitle: function() {        
        this.set("title", "Home");
    }.on('init')
});
```

I updated your jsbin with this implementation http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1745/edit